# Android Instrumentation Tests: unable to add a class to a folder androidTest/java

Tags: android, junit

Steps I have done to solve the problem:

**1**)
    build.gradle:
    sourceSets {
       androidTest {
           java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java']
       }
    }

**2**) Run - Edit configuration - + Android Tests - add new configuration (All in Module, Specific instrumentation runner (optional) - android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, Target - Emulator).

**3**) Sync Project with Gradle files.

**4**) Build Variants - Android Instrumentation Tests.

But the folder **androidTest/java** doesn't change the **color**. And I cannot add class test.

**How can I overcome this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/instrumentTest', 'src/instrumentTest/java', 'src/test/java', 'androidTest/java']
    }
    test {
        java.srcDirs = ['androidTest/java', 'src/test/java', 'src/test/java/']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
    }
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't change the color